# Is there a better way to process a 300,000 line text file data and insert it into MySQL?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, database, text-files

What I'm doing right now is reading the contents of the text file and store it in a variable. After reading the whole content, I run a loop for the chunk data and in there call a function that will read to each line of the chunk data and pass every line to another function that process the processing of each column of data and inserting it in the database by batch. The batch is the whole chunk.

The code process too long for every file with more than 500KB size. My problem is there is no unique identifier in the text file that I can use so that I can apply "LOAD DATA INFILE" which put me in this situation of processing the text file by chunks.

The 700K took almost the whole day in processing but still it depends on the machine specifications. The code runs in an CentOS. After the first text file processed the next text file with 800KB++ size took almost a week to process. In these goes with the other text file with more than 800KB size, took almost or more than a week to process especially the 1MB size file.

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong and what are the options I need to make my code run efficiently.

---

```
/*
====================================================================================
                RECORDS FETCH 
====================================================================================

Needs path and filename with extension.
The page do an iteration of records in the file by line.
After by line, it iterates again per delimiter ","..
It concatenates the part of the records for bulk insert process.
PID address is incremental, every three PID correspond to one Chamber
and the reading in each Chamber is CO2 for first PID address, RH for the
second PID address, TEMP for the third PID address.


====================================================================================
*/
$path = "";
$filename = "";
error_reporting(0);
include_once ("connect.php");
$p_results = mysql_query("SELECT PATH, FILENAME FROM tbl_path"); 
if(mysql_num_rows($p_results) > 0 ){
while ( $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($p_results) )
{
    $path = $rows['PATH'];
    $filename = $rows['FILENAME'];
}
}
else
{
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_log (LOG_DATE, DETAILS) VALUES ( NOW(), 'There is no path and filename to be accessed. Please provide.' )");
}
$path = str_replace('\\','/',$path);
//holds the path..NOTE: Change backslash (\) to forward slash (/)
//$path = "E:/";
//holds the filename.. NOTE: Include the file extension
//$filename = "sample2.txt"; //"chamber_1_con.txt";
if ($path <> "" && $filename <> "")
     is_connected($path, $filename);

echo ('<script language="javascript">window.location = "chambers_monitoring.php"  </script>');

//function for DB writing in table data
function InsertData($rec, &$errorDataCnt, &$sql, $y, $i, $x, &$dCnt)
{

$dDate = (!isset($rec[0]) ? 0 : (trim($rec[0]) == "" ? 0 : trim($rec[0]))); 
$dTime = (!isset($rec[1]) ? 0 : (trim($rec[1]) == "" ? 0 : trim($rec[1]))); 
$address = (!isset($rec[2]) ? 0 : (trim($rec[2]) == "" ? 0 : trim($rec[2]))); 
$co2SV = (!isset($rec[3]) ? 0 : (trim($rec[3]) == "" ? 0 : trim($rec[3]))); 
$co2PV = (!isset($rec[4]) ? 0 : (trim($rec[4]) == "" ? 0 : trim($rec[4]))); 
$tempSV = (!isset($rec[5]) ? 0 : (trim($rec[5]) == "" ? 0 : trim($rec[5]))); 
$tempPV = (!isset($rec[6]) ? 0 : (trim($rec[6]) == "" ? 0 : trim($rec[6]))); 
$rhSV = (!isset($rec[7]) ? 0 : (trim($rec[7]) == "" ? 0 : trim($rec[7]))); 
$rhPV = (!isset($rec[8]) ? 0 : (trim($rec[8]) == "" ? 0 : trim($rec[8]))); 


    /* include('connect.php'); */
    set_time_limit(36000);
    ini_set('max_execution_time','43200');
    $e_results = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM tbl_reading WHERE (READING_DATE = '".date("Y-m-d",strtotime($dDate))."' AND READING_TIME = '".date("H:i:s",strtotime($dTime))."') AND READING_ADDRESS = $address LIMIT 1"); 
    if(mysql_num_rows($e_results) <= 0 ){
      if (!($dDate == 0 || $dTime == 0 || $address == 0) ) {
        if ($y == 0){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_reading (READING_DATE,   READING_TIME, READING_ADDRESS, CO2_SET_VALUE, CO2_PROCESS_VALUE, TEMP_SET_VALUE, TEMP_PROCESS_VALUE, RH_SET_VALUE, RH_PROCESS_VALUE) VALUES ('".date("Y/m/d",strtotime($dDate))."','".date("H:i:s",strtotime($dTime))."', ".  mysql_real_escape_string($address).",". mysql_real_escape_string($co2SV).",". mysql_real_escape_string($co2PV).",". mysql_real_escape_string($tempSV).",". mysql_real_escape_string($tempPV).",". mysql_real_escape_string($rhSV).",". mysql_real_escape_string($rhPV).")";
        }
        else {
            $sql .= ",   ('".date("Y/m/d",strtotime($dDate))."','".date("H:i:s",strtotime($dTime))."', ". mysql_real_escape_string($address).",". mysql_real_escape_string($co2SV).",". mysql_real_escape_string($co2PV).",". mysql_real_escape_string($tempSV).",". mysql_real_escape_string($tempPV).",". mysql_real_escape_string($rhSV).",". mysql_real_escape_string($rhPV).")";

        }
       }
      }

        if(($x + 1) == $i){
            //echo ($x + 1)." = ".$i."<br>";
            if (substr($sql, 0, 1) == ",")
                $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_reading (READING_DATE, READING_TIME, READING_ADDRESS, CO2_SET_VALUE, CO2_PROCESS_VALUE, TEMP_SET_VALUE, TEMP_PROCESS_VALUE, RH_SET_VALUE, RH_PROCESS_VALUE) VALUES".substr($sql, 1);
            //echo $sql."<br>";
            set_time_limit(36000);
            try {

                $result = mysql_query($sql) ;
                $dCnt = mysql_affected_rows();
                if( $dCnt  == 0)
                {
                    $errorDataCnt = $errorDataCnt + 1;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception $e)
            {
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_log (LOG_DATE,  DETAILS) VALUES ( NOW(), '".$e->getMessage()."' )");
            }
            //mysql_free_result($result);
        }

unset($dDate); 
unset($dTime); 
unset($address); 
unset($co2SV); 
unset($co2PV); 
unset($tempSV); 
unset($tempPV); 
unset($rhSV); 
unset($rhPV);  

 }

//function for looping into the records per line
function loop($data)
{
$errorDataCnt = 0; $sql = ""; $exist = 0;
$i = count( $data); $x = 0; $y = 0; $tmpAdd = ""; $cnt = 0; $t = 0; $dCnt = 0; 

ini_set('max_execution_time','43200');
while($x < $i) 
{
    $rec = explode(",", $data[$x]); 
    InsertData($rec, $errorDataCnt, $sql, $y, $i, $x, $dCnt);
    $x++; 
    $y++;
    unset($rec);
}

    $errFetch = ($i - $dCnt);
if($errorDataCnt > 0)
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_log (LOG_DATE, DETAILS) VALUES ( NOW(), 'Error inserting $errFetch records. Check if there is a NULL or empty value or if it is the correct data type.' )");
if($dCnt > 0)
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_log (LOG_DATE, DETAILS) VALUES ( NOW(), 'Saved   $dCnt of $i records into the database. Total $exist records already existing in the database.' )");


}

// functions in looping records and passing into $contents variable
function DataLoop($file)
{
ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);
set_time_limit(36000);
ini_set('max_execution_time','43200');
$contents = ''; $j = 0;
if ($handle = fopen($file,"rb")){
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $rdata = fgets($handle, 3359232);//filesize($file));
        //$rdata = fread($handle, filesize($file));
        if(trim($rdata) != "" || $rdata === FALSE){
            if (feof($handle)) break;
            else {
            $contents .= $rdata;
            $j = $j + 1; }}
    }   
    fclose($handle);
    $data = explode("\n", $contents);
    unset($contents);
    unset($rdata);
}
/* echo count($contents)." ".count($data); */
/* $query = "SELECT MAX(`ID`) AS `max` FROM `tbl_reading`";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$max = $row['max']; */
/* $res =   mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM  tbl_reading")) or die(mysql_error());
echo "<script>alert('".$res['total']."')</script>"; */
$p = 0;
ini_set('memory_limit','512M');
if($j != 0)
{
    foreach(array_chunk($data, ceil(count($data)/200)) as $rec_data){
        loop($rec_data);
        $p++;
    }
} 

}
//function to test if filename exists
function IsExist($file)
{
if ($con = fopen($file, "r"))// file_exists($file))
{
    fclose($con);
    DataLoop($file);
}
else
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_log (LOG_DATE, DETAILS) VALUES ( NOW(), '$filename is not existing in $path. Check if the filename or the path is correct.' )");

}

//function to test connection to where the file is.
function is_connected($path, $filename)
{
//check to see if the local machine is connected to the network 
$errno = ""; $errstr = ""; 
if (substr(trim($path), -1) == '/')
  $file = $path.$filename;
else
    $file = $path."/".$filename; 

IsExist($file);

}
```

Comment: First off, you should replace mysql(which is deprecated, and will be removed most likely in the next major version) with mysqli or PDO. This could also be a performance increase.

Comment: The obvious question would be "why on earth are you doing databases in PHP"? The other obvious remark would be that you should just be reading the file line-by-line, not the whole thing at once.

Comment: have you ever run a profiler for your script to have a better understanding of what are the bottlenecks?

Comment: IMHO `LOAD DATA INFILE` is still on the plate. You don't necessarily need to have a unique identifier to use it. Load your files to staging table(or tables) and then do your cleaning, normalizing etc. whatever you do and then insert your data to your factual tables.

Comment: Vlad Preda: I'll try using PDO. I'm just a newbie in PHP. Hope there would be  a performance increase.

Comment: @peterm - that's an option but it still add up to the process as there will be still scripts needed for that.

Comment: @AndrejBauer: This is a web-based application and PHP is one of the open source server side script we're using since then..do you have any suggestion script language other than PHP? If I read it line by line the server script for insert would just hang-up that's why I'm doing a batch insert.

Comment: @Mahdi: I have run several files with just less than 500KB of text file size and it just took not more than 3 hours.

Comment: EVERYONE IS RIGHT. The bottleneck is on comparison of data in the text file and in the table if there exist a record with the same reading date, time and address, as table will grow bigger every time there's a new data to insert.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I really don't want that select statement in there. It eats so much time and process but I don't know what to replace it as I can't have anything to check duplication. As you can see LOAD DATA INFILE can't be used in my data.

Is there any other web-based scripts that I can use to make this efficient and reliable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your code, it appears that your "unique identifier" (for the purposes of this insertion, at least) is the composite `(READING_DATE, READING_TIME, READING_ADDRESS)`.

If you define such a `UNIQUE` key in your database, then [`LOAD DATA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html) with the `IGNORE` keyword should do exactly what you require:

```sql
ALTER TABLE tbl_reading
  ADD UNIQUE KEY (READING_DATE, READING_TIME, READING_ADDRESS)
;

LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/csv'
    IGNORE
    INTO TABLE tbl_reading
    FIELDS
        TERMINATED BY ','
        OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
        ESCAPED BY ''
    LINES
        TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
    (@rec_0, @rec_1, @rec_2, @rec_3, @rec_4, @rec_5, @rec_6, @rec_7, @rec_8)
    SET
        READING_DATE = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(TRIM(@rec_0), '???'), '%Y/%m/%d'),
        READING_TIME = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(TRIM(@rec_1), '???'), '%H:%i:%s'),
        READING_ADDRESS    = TRIM(@rec_2),
        CO2_SET_VALUE      = TRIM(@rec_3),
        CO2_PROCESS_VALUE  = TRIM(@rec_4),
        TEMP_SET_VALUE     = TRIM(@rec_5),
        TEMP_PROCESS_VALUE = TRIM(@rec_6),
        RH_SET_VALUE       = TRIM(@rec_7),
        RH_PROCESS_VALUE   = TRIM(@rec_8)
;
```

(Where `'???'` are replaced with strings that represent the date and time formats in your CSV).

Note that you should really be storing `READING_DATE` and `READING_TIME` together in a single `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE tbl_reading
  ADD COLUMN READING_DATETIME DATETIME AFTER READING_TIME,
  ADD UNIQUE KEY (READING_DATETIME, READING_ADDRESS)
;

UPDATE tbl_reading SET READING_DATETIME = STR_TO_DATE(
  CONCAT(READING_DATE, ' ', READING_TIME),
  '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s'
);

ALTER TABLE tbl_reading
  DROP COLUMN READING_DATE,
  DROP COLUMN READING_TIME
;
```

In which case, the `SET` clause of the `LOAD DATA` command would include instead:

```sql
READING_DATETIME = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(TRIM(@rec_0), ' ', TRIM(@rec_1)), '???')
```

Comment: that wouldn't be a pleasant db structure then..and a code block for the concatenation would just add to the decrease in performance..
what do you think?..

Comment: @AristonAlcantara: What do you mean "*that wouldn't be a pleasant db structure*"?  The only changes I propose to your structure are the definition of a uniqueness constraint to enforce the logic you have in your PHP; and (optionally, but highly recommended) the replacement of two string columns with a single temporal one where appropriate.  I'm not sure what you mean by "*a code block for the concatenation*", but I guarantee the performance of the above `LOAD DATA` command will be **significantly** better than your PHP.

Comment: thanks for the idea..haven't used "LOAD DATA INFILE" before.
but I can't make the reading date and time concatenated as it is used for making a graph and in other script.. and I can't have a unique reading date and time as the reading is every 30 seconds..

Comment: @AristonAlcantara: Just because the data is stored in the database "*concatenated*" (as you say), does not mean that it need be fetched in that manner; for example, one could `SELECT DATE(READING_DATETIME) AS READING_DATE, TIME(READING_DATETIME) AS READING_TIME, ...`.  I'm not sure what you mean by "*I can't have a unique reading date and time*", as that is exactly the logic you are already implementing in your PHP with `if(mysql_num_rows($e_results) <= 0 ) ...`.

Comment: @AristonAlcantara: Would *what* create redundancy?

Comment: if I would have a field containing the three fields concatenated..would that somewhat make it redundant?
sorry if I can't gets what you're saying..

Comment: @AristonAlcantara: I am *not* suggesting "*concatenating*" three fields.  I am proposing, **at your option**, combining the date and time into a single MySQL `DATETIME` field - this should make searches and manipulation of your data *more* efficient, not less.  Even if you choose not to do this, you might consider using MySQL's temporal `DATE` and `TIME` types for the separate columns.

Comment: I see. I'm weighing the options. The web-based application is up and running. A single change in the db structure will affect all the files. Even if I use a single field for datetime there is still no unique identifier for LOAD DATA INFILE as there are 10 address as well where some address have the same date and time.

Your post is correct, I need the date, time and address composite but the problem is the text file is not in my control.

Comment: @AristonAlcantara: As explained in my answer, your "unique identifier" is the composite of the three columns.  As explained in my first comment above, you do not **need** to make any change to the database structure except adding a `UNIQUE` index (which will not affect the format of data entering or exiting the database and therefore should not present any problem); *even if* you implement my recommended change to the schema, it need not affect the format of your files or your report per the examples I have given.  I cannot understand what difficulty you are having with this?

Comment: As what I'm trying to say is that I can't make date and time neither address "UNIQUE". Here is a sample of the data need to be inserted:
12/01/2012,07:32:28, 2, 30, 28, 27, 26.6, 60, 67
12/01/2012,07:32:28, 3, 30, 124, 27, 26.9, 60, 66
12/01/2012,07:32:28, 5, 30, 53, 27, 27.4, 60, 62
12/01/2012,07:32:48, 2, 30, 28, 27, 26.9, 60, 67
12/01/2012,07:32:48, 3, 30, 121, 27, 27.4, 60, 69
12/01/2012,07:32:48, 5, 30, 52, 27, 27.3, 60, 62
12/01/2012,07:33:08, 2, 30, 29, 27, 27.1, 60, 67
12/01/2012,07:33:08, 3, 30, 119, 27, 28.1, 60, 70
12/01/2012,07:33:08, 5, 30, 51, 27, 27.3, 60, 62

Comment: Thanks for the help. I really don't want that select statement in there. It eats so much time and process but I don't know what to replace it as I can't have anything to check duplication. As you can see LOAD DATA INFILE can't be used in my data.

Comment: @AristonAlcantara: I am not saying that you make *one* of date, time and address unique - but rather the *combination* of all three.  As you can see above, `LOAD DATA INFILE` *can* be used on your data.

Comment: Sorry for being a novice. 
How can I apply that?
Should I create a new field in my DB for the three composite values? And another block of code for the concatenation of the three values?

Comment: @AristonAlcantara: The necessary SQL command is in my answer: `ALTER TABLE tbl_reading ADD UNIQUE KEY (READING_DATE, READING_TIME, READING_ADDRESS)`.

Comment: Thanks. I understand now. Now I now that concept. Before it is vague in me.

Answer (score 2):

Reading a 1 MB file line by line takes less than a second. Even concatenating and then again splitting  all lines doesn't take any amount of time.

With a simple test, inserting 100,000 rows took about 90 seconds.

*But*, doing a select query before the insert, increases the time needed by more than an order of magnitude.

The lesson to learn from this is, if you need to insert large amounts of data, do it in big chunks (see [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html)). If you can't do this for whatever reasons, do inserts and inserts *alone*.

*Update*:

As @eggyal already suggested, add a unique key to your table definition. In my small, one column test, I added a unique key and changed `insert` to `insert ignore`. Wall clock time increased 15%-30% (~100-110 sec), which is much better than the increase to 38 min (25 times!) with separate select + insert.

So, as a conclusion, (stealing from eggyal) add

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_reading
  ADD UNIQUE KEY (READING_DATE, READING_TIME, READING_ADDRESS)
```

to your table, remove the `select` in `InsertData()` and change `insert` to `insert ignore`.

Comment: Again, I can't use LOAD DATA INFILE as I don't have a unique identifier of the fields.

Comment: @AristonAlcantara Then you should avoid the `select` in `InsertData()`. My simple test, just one column, took 90 sec (insert alone) vs 38 min (select + insert).

Comment: But I need to compare data to avoid duplicates.

Comment: @AristonAlcantara As eggyal has shown, you can add a unique index over `READING_DATE, READING_TIME, READING_ADDRESS` and then use `LOAD DATA INFILE`. You can also use `insert ignore` with this unique index, but load data infile is much faster.

Comment: How can I make it unique when duplication of such field will occur?
For it to be unique, READING_DATE, READING_TIME and READING_ADDRESS must be a composite as eggyal said, but making it composite will just add another process and editing of the DB structure.

Comment: @AristonAlcantara You can leave the table structure as it is and just add the unique index. This is sufficient to make `insert ignore` or `load data infile` work.

Comment: I know but I commented to eggyal post the sample data that will be inserted to make what I'm saying clear and let anyone knows why I can't make it unique.

Comment: @AristonAlcantara Date is not unique, time is not unique and address is not unique, *but* date+time+address combined is unique. That is what you already do in your PHP script, when you check for duplicates in your select.

Comment: Here are some sample data to be inserted: 12/01/2012,07:32:28, 2, 30, 28, 27, 26.6, 60, 67 12/01/2012,07:32:28, 3, 30, 124, 27, 26.9, 60, 66 12/01/2012,07:32:28, 5, 30, 53, 27, 27.4, 60, 62 12/01/2012,07:32:48, 2, 30, 28, 27, 26.9, 60, 67 12/01/2012,07:32:48, 3, 30, 121, 27, 27.4, 60, 69 12/01/2012,07:32:48, 5, 30, 52, 27, 27.3, 60, 62 12/01/2012,07:33:08, 2, 30, 29, 27, 27.1, 60, 67 12/01/2012,07:33:08, 3, 30, 119, 27, 28.1, 60, 70 12/01/2012,07:33:08, 5, 30, 51, 27, 27.3, 60, 62
 As you can see there is duplication with those fields that's why I can't make it unique. Is it possible?

Comment: @AristonAlcantara I have everything written in my update. I can't say more, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I really don't want that select statement in there. It eats so much time and process but I don't know what to replace it as I can't have anything to check duplication. As you can see LOAD DATA INFILE can't be used in my data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make some preparations before starting your inserts because InnoDB engine makes inserts too slow with default settings.

either set this option before insert

```
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
```

or make all your inserts into one transaction.
And it will be blazing fast, no matter what syntax or driver you choose.

Comment: will that not create error if the other table is in different engine?