# Need assistance in changing multiple or batch insert queries to PDO

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, pdo

I have asked a question in this link [Is-there-a-better-way-to-process-a-300-000-line-text-file-data-and-insert-it-into-a-mysql-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453922/is-there-a-better-way-to-process-a-300-000-line-text-file-data-and-insert-it-int) and posted my code.

Now I want to change the queries into a PDO, but I'm having difficulties in changing the queries in the InsertData function. I'm new in PDO so can anyone help me? Don't know what to do with the insert statement doing batch insert.

What I'm thinking is inserting it one by one, but is it efficient as I'm posting that question for performance efficiency?

```
//function for DB writing in table data
function InsertData($rec, &$errorDataCnt, &$sql, $y, $i, $x, &$dCnt)
{

    $dDate = (!isset($rec[0]) ? 0 : (trim($rec[0]) == "" ? 0 : trim($rec[0]))); 
    $dTime = (!isset($rec[1]) ? 0 : (trim($rec[1]) == "" ? 0 : trim($rec[1]))); 
    $address = (!isset($rec[2]) ? 0 : (trim($rec[2]) == "" ? 0 : trim($rec[2]))); 
    $co2SV = (!isset($rec[3]) ? 0 : (trim($rec[3]) == "" ? 0 : trim($rec[3]))); 
    $co2PV = (!isset($rec[4]) ? 0 : (trim($rec[4]) == "" ? 0 : trim($rec[4]))); 
    $tempSV = (!isset($rec[5]) ? 0 : (trim($rec[5]) == "" ? 0 : trim($rec[5]))); 
    $tempPV = (!isset($rec[6]) ? 0 : (trim($rec[6]) == "" ? 0 : trim($rec[6]))); 
    $rhSV = (!isset($rec[7]) ? 0 : (trim($rec[7]) == "" ? 0 : trim($rec[7]))); 
    $rhPV = (!isset($rec[8]) ? 0 : (trim($rec[8]) == "" ? 0 : trim($rec[8]))); 


        /* include('connect.php'); */
        set_time_limit(36000);
        ini_set('max_execution_time','43200');
        $e_results = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM tbl_reading WHERE (READING_DATE = '".date("Y-m-d",strtotime($dDate))."' AND READING_TIME = '".date("H:i:s",strtotime($dTime))."') AND READING_ADDRESS = $address LIMIT 1"); 
        if(mysql_num_rows($e_results) <= 0 ){
          if (!($dDate == 0 || $dTime == 0 || $address == 0) ) {
            if ($y == 0){
                $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_reading (READING_DATE, READING_TIME, READING_ADDRESS, CO2_SET_VALUE, CO2_PROCESS_VALUE, TEMP_SET_VALUE, TEMP_PROCESS_VALUE, RH_SET_VALUE, RH_PROCESS_VALUE) VALUES ('".date("Y/m/d",strtotime($dDate))."','".date("H:i:s",strtotime($dTime))."', ". mysql_real_escape_string($address).",". mysql_real_escape_string($co2SV).",". mysql_real_escape_string($co2PV).",". mysql_real_escape_string($tempSV).",". mysql_real_escape_string($tempPV).",". mysql_real_escape_string($rhSV).",". mysql_real_escape_string($rhPV).")";
            }
            else {
                $sql .= ", ('".date("Y/m/d",strtotime($dDate))."','".date("H:i:s",strtotime($dTime))."', ". mysql_real_escape_string($address).",". mysql_real_escape_string($co2SV).",". mysql_real_escape_string($co2PV).",". mysql_real_escape_string($tempSV).",". mysql_real_escape_string($tempPV).",". mysql_real_escape_string($rhSV).",". mysql_real_escape_string($rhPV).")";

            }
           }
          }

            if(($x + 1) == $i){
                //echo ($x + 1)." = ".$i."<br>";
                if (substr($sql, 0, 1) == ",")
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_reading (READING_DATE, READING_TIME, READING_ADDRESS, CO2_SET_VALUE, CO2_PROCESS_VALUE, TEMP_SET_VALUE, TEMP_PROCESS_VALUE, RH_SET_VALUE, RH_PROCESS_VALUE) VALUES".substr($sql, 1);
                //echo $sql."<br>";
                set_time_limit(36000);
                try {

                    $result = mysql_query($sql) ;
                    $dCnt = mysql_affected_rows();
                    if( $dCnt  == 0)
                    {
                        $errorDataCnt = $errorDataCnt + 1;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception $e)
                {
                    $conn->query("INSERT INTO tbl_log (LOG_DATE, DETAILS) VALUES ( NOW(), '".$e->getMessage()."' )");
                }
                //mysql_free_result($result);
            }

    unset($dDate); 
    unset($dTime); 
    unset($address); 
    unset($co2SV); 
    unset($co2PV); 
    unset($tempSV); 
    unset($tempPV); 
    unset($rhSV); 
    unset($rhPV);  

}

//function for looping into the records per line
function loop($data)
{
    $errorDataCnt = 0; $sql = ""; $exist = 0;
    $i = count( $data); $x = 0; $y = 0; $tmpAdd = ""; $cnt = 0; $t = 0; $dCnt = 0; 

    ini_set('max_execution_time','43200');
    while($x < $i) 
    {
        $rec = explode(",", $data[$x]); 
        InsertData($rec, $errorDataCnt, $sql, $y, $i, $x, $dCnt);
        $x++; 
        $y++;
        unset($rec);
    }

        $errFetch = ($i - $dCnt);
    if($errorDataCnt > 0)
        $conn->query("INSERT INTO tbl_log (LOG_DATE, DETAILS) VALUES ( NOW(), 'Error inserting $errFetch records. Check if there is a NULL or empty value or if it is the correct data type.' )");
    if($dCnt > 0)
        $conn->query("INSERT INTO tbl_log (LOG_DATE, DETAILS) VALUES ( NOW(), 'Saved $dCnt of $i records into the database. Total $exist records already existing in the database.' )");


}

// functions in looping records and passing into $contents variable
function DataLoop($file)
{
    ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);
    set_time_limit(36000);
    ini_set('max_execution_time','43200');
    $contents = ''; $j = 0;
    if ($handle = fopen($file,"rb")){
        while (!feof($handle)) {
            $rdata = fgets($handle, 3359232);//filesize($file));
            //$rdata = fread($handle, filesize($file));
            if(trim($rdata) != "" || $rdata === FALSE){
                if (feof($handle)) break;
                else {
                $contents .= $rdata;
                $j = $j + 1; }}
        }   
        fclose($handle);
        $data = explode("\n", $contents);
        unset($contents);
        unset($rdata);
    }
    /* echo count($contents)." ".count($data); */
    /* $query = "SELECT MAX(`ID`) AS `max` FROM `tbl_reading`";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $max = $row['max']; */
    /* $res =   mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM tbl_reading")) or die(mysql_error());
    echo "<script>alert('".$res['total']."')</script>"; */
    $p = 0;
    ini_set('memory_limit','512M');
    if($j != 0)
    {
        foreach(array_chunk($data, ceil(count($data)/200)) as $rec_data){
            loop($rec_data);
            $p++;
        }
    } 

}
```

Comment: I have tried a one by one insert of the data using PDO. 
I'm processing hundred thousands of line of data in a text file which must be efficiently transfer in a much better performance.

I'm having difficulty in creating a PDO batch insert, as I want to process it by batch.
You can visit the link of my first question to see my code.

Comment: show `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for your table

Comment: CREATE TABLE `tbl_reading` (
 `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `READING_DATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `READING_TIME` time DEFAULT NULL,
 `READING_ADDRESS` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `CO2_SET_VALUE` double DEFAULT NULL,
 `CO2_PROCESS_VALUE` double DEFAULT NULL,
 `TEMP_SET_VALUE` double DEFAULT NULL,
 `TEMP_PROCESS_VALUE` double DEFAULT NULL,
 `RH_SET_VALUE` double DEFAULT NULL,
 `RH_PROCESS_VALUE` double DEFAULT NULL,
 `isArchive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=611272 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PDO::prepare` for that. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

It is meant for something like this and should be a little bit faster (not actually talking from experience). Just measure it with some sample data.

```
$data = array(
     array(
         ':key1' => 'value1',
         ':key2' => 'value2',
     ),
     array(
         ':key1' => 'value3',
         ':key2' => 'value4',
     ),
);

$sql = 'INSERT INTO data_table (key1, key1) VALUES (:key1, key2);';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
foreach($data AS $dataset) {
    $stmt->execute($dataset);
}
```

Comment: I have added my code. Can you help me with the batch insert?
SO that I can test which one is much efficient between the batch insert or the one by one insertion.

Comment: I would pass all data (as an array) to the InsertData method, create a statement (like in the example) for the insert query, then loop over the array, prepare the data, and execute the query with $stmt->execute.

I'm not gonna do the work for try. Try to play around with it a little bit, rewrite some parts and if you're really stuck, then ask again.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the way you're running your queries (PDO, mysql, bulk inserts or whatever) but InnoDB engine that makes inserts too slow.
You need to make some preparetions before starting your inserts.
As for the particular inserts syntax - it's irrelevant.

either set this option before insert

```
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
```

or make all your inserts into one transaction.
And it will be blazing fast, no matter what syntax or driver you choose

Comment: That's my problem. I can't inserts into one transaction. Process hangs-up because of the duplicate comparison.